# "Отлить из олова" или "отлить в олове"?

Tags: орфография

Несколько часов длятся дебаты. Отлить "из олова" или "в олове"? Или оба варианта возможны?

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, смысл один, но "отлить в олове" — это более... отвлеченно, что ли, даже пафосно. А вот "отлить из олова" — прозаичнее, с конкретным указанием материала.

Answer (score 0):

Отлить из олова (т.е. материал из которого что-то отливают)ср.напр. отлить из чугуна.А отлить из олова как-то неясно.Получается ,что олово - это форма,в которой что-то отливают.